# Uniform convergence of an infinite product of automorphisms of the unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product

I need to show that $\Pi \frac{|a_n|}{a_n} \frac{a_n - z}{1-\overline{a_n}z}$ with $\{a_n\} \subset D(0,1)$ and $\Sigma$ $(1 -|a_n|) < \infty$ converges to a holomorphic function in $D(0,1)$

It's clear that each $\frac{a_n - z}{1-\overline{a_n}z}=\varphi_{a_{n}}$ with $\varphi_{a_{n}}$ an automorphism of the unit disk.

Each term of the infinite product is bounded and $|a_n|$ converges to 1 because $\Sigma$ $(1 -|a_n|) < \infty$

I'm trying to use this:

> Let $\{f_n \}$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions in an open set of the complex plane ($\Omega$)  if
>
> $\Sigma$ $|f_n - 1 |$ converges uniformly on the compact sets of $\Omega$ then $\Pi \{f_n \}$ also converges.

The problem is that i'm not finding anything useful with the manipulations of $|f_n -1|$. Any advice?

Comment: These are called Blaschke products.

Comment: Well Rudin (pg 310 Real and Complex Analysis) uses two lines.. but there's no way I can justify the last inequality.

Comment: What did you get for $\varphi_{a_n}(z) - 1$ after simplifying?

Comment: $|(1-|a_n|)|$ $|\frac{|a_n|z +a_n}{(1- \overline{a_n}z) a_n}|$

Comment: OK. In absolute value, that numerator is $<2.$ If $|z|<r,$ how small can that the abs value of the denominator be?